# sql syntax using php session array variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hello I have SQL syntax error using PHP, My code is

```
     $_SESSION['reparray']=array();
    $com = $conn->prepare("select * from replies where rep_com_id=? AND rep_id NOT IN(".implode(',',$_SESSION['reparray']).") order by likes desc limit 10");
    $com->execute(array($_POST['id']));
    $fetchcom = $com->fetchAll();
    foreach ($fetchcom as $com_column ){
    array_push($_SESSION['reparray'], $com_column['rep_id'] );
```

I am using the same code with just different variables in other pages,  its working fine but here i am getting error like this :

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') order by likes desc limit 10' at line 1 in C:\wamp64\www\randomz.com\functions\getrep.php on line 9

Comment: If you're setting the array just before the query then it is empty and the `IN` statement will be empty too.

Comment: When in doubt, `echo`/`var_dump()`/`print_r()` are your friends.

Comment: I tryed to add values in array manually, yes its not showing any errors, but fetching the same comments more than 1 times..

Comment: yes @Mike i tred it, its olride, array_push is working fine

Comment: "*but fetching the same comments more than 1 times*" - Have the comments been posted multiple times with the same text and a different comment ID?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want the `reparray` to accumulate the `id` values that you have already collected in the session. But as the array is initialised as an empty array, the SQL will have this condition:

```
IN ()
```

... which is invalid SQL syntax.

You could solve that by concatenating a dummy value to your array; a value that never occurs in your table. Let's assume -1 is such a value. Then add `+ [-1]` like this:

```
implode(',',$_SESSION['reparray'] + [-1])
```

Comment: I tryed it, not showing me any erros, but fetching same comments again.

Comment: I have the same SQL querry just with different variables, its working fine.. is have a any  PHP max_session limit ?? i dont know,

Comment: But "fetching the same comments" is a different question. Your question stated "I have a SQL syntax error...", and the title has again "SQL syntax". Now you are telling me you don't have an error. So is your question about the error solved?